# Is the phrase 'there is no one single form' correct?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Is it correct to write 'there is no one single form of ...'?

Is this an example of tautology? Or, is this terminology used for a matter of emphasis? Is there a nuance between the word 'one' and 'single' that makes this necessary, and if so, should there be a comma between 'one' and 'single'?

Examples from my internet search are shown below (usage without the comma appears in the majority of instances):

*Just as there is no one single form of literature to express the rich diversity of human culture ...*

*There is no one single form of democracy ...*

*There is currently no one, single form of treatment for ...*